# Sorting a select with fractions in jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to sort the below select options by their computed fractional value, excluding the --please select-- option.

```
<select class="wpsc_select_variation">
<option value="0">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="13">1"</option>
<option value="21">2''</option>
<option value="11">3/4"</option>
<option value="6">3/8"</option>
<option value="10">5/8"</option>
<option value="17">1-1/2''</option>
<option value="15">1-1/4''</option>
<option value="19">1-3/4''</option>
<option value="7">1/2"</option>
</select>
```

Code I've put together so far:
Added to pastebin for brevity and history's sake.

### [Link](http://pastebin.com/8reTt8sR)

This would explain the length of the note 1 array being 3.
But why is it 3? Why isn't it 9?
Why does Chrome show the full array, but still have a length of 3, and Firefox show the full array after clicking the parent +, but the parent says undefined, option, option?

Confused...

EDITS:
Edit to allow for multiple select boxes:
Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
$(".wpsc_select_variation").each(function(index, element){
        $($(element).children().get().sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseInt(a.value) - parseInt(b.value);
        })).appendTo($(element));
    });
```

Latest edit using objects.
Here goes:

```
var els = new Array();
var counter = 0;
$j("select.wpsc_select_variation option").each(function(index, ele){
var obj = new Object;
var i = $j(ele).text();
i = i.replace("\"", "");
i = i.replace("''", "");
if (i.indexOf("-") >= 0){
    i = i.split('-');
    split = i[1].split('/');
    i = eval(i[0]) + split[0] / split[1];
}
else if(i.indexOf("/") >= 0){
    split = i.split('/');
    i = split[0] / split[1];
}
i = eval(i);
obj.ind = i;
obj.ele = ele;
els[counter] = obj;
counter++;
});
els.sort(function (a, b) { return parseInt(a.ind) - parseInt(b.ind) });
console.log(els);
```

The above results in:

```
[Object { ind=NaN,  ele=option}, Object { ind=0.75,  ele=option}, Object { ind=0.375,  ele=option}, Object { ind=0.625,  ele=option}, Object { ind=0.5,  ele=option}, Object { ind=1,  ele=option}, Object { ind=1.5,  ele=option}, Object { ind=1.25,  ele=option}, Object { ind=1.75,  ele=option}, Object { ind=2,  ele=option}]
```

It appears to be sorting them somewhat, but as you can see, they are still out of order.

Comment: I realize that this code may be a bit on the slow side and could use some enhancements in general. Please feel free to shamelessly hack away at my code if you see room for improvement.

Comment: Non-integer number keys are not valid. Instead they are treated as strings and applied as keys to an object property rather than an array index.

Comment: Their values seem to be in order: http://jsfiddle.net/MG3XM/

Comment: Holy cow @ExplosionPills - I knew I should have come here first. Your solution completely eradicates the need for any of my code. Can you make it into a solution so I can accept it?

Comment: @Kolink - I think I see what you mean. So is the code I posted above completely worthless?

Comment: What does `1-1/2` means? 1 minus 1/2 (0.5) or 1 plus 1/2 (1.5), because, if its minus, then @ExplosionPills answer is not correct ...

Comment: It's 1 & 1/2. Typical fraction notation, right? btw, is your name really Toni Almeida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following jsfiddle resolves this question. Credit goes to ExplosionPills for his general help and Kolink for helping me discover more about arrays. Thanks to vol7ron here:
[Turning an array of jquery objects into html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900115/turning-an-array-of-jquery-objects-into-html) for his help with the functions.
Thanks guys!

```
function sortByRationalValue (a,b){
        return a.rationalValue - b.rationalValue;
    }
function returnObjectFromMeasurements(element, text) {
    var obj = {},
        range = text.replace(/["'”″]/g, '').split('-'),
        rational;

    if (range.length > 1)
        rational = eval(range[0]) + eval(range[1]);
    else
        rational = eval(range[0]);

    obj.rationalValue = rational;
    obj.element       = element;
    return obj;
}
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".wpsc_select_variation").each(function (index, element) {
        var els = new Array();
        var counter = 0;
        var children = $(element).children();
        $(children).each(function (index, ele) {
            els[index] = returnObjectFromMeasurements(ele, $(ele).text());
        });
        els.sort(sortByRationalValue);
        var elements = new Array();
        $.each(els, function (index, value) {
            elements[index] = value.element;
        });
        $(this).html(elements);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwWJ3/5/

Answer (score 2):

Since the option *values* are already in the order you need, you can just sort on those:

```
$($(".select_variation option").get().sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.value) - parseInt(b.value);
})).appendTo(".select_variation");
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have run into a small glitch - there are multiple select's on the same pge, with the same class that need the same logic applied.

Comment: @JoshLevinson wrap this in a `.each` callback on the selects.  If they weren't in order then I guess we would have to do more work sorting by the text which gave you so much trouble in the first place.  We can address that in another question perhaps

Comment: What if the values were _not_ in order? This is a drop-down generated by posts (WordPress) that may not always be generated in the same order. The posts are sequentially numbered upon creation. The option values are the post id's. For instance, I might create a post for 1", then come back and create on for 3/8". The 3/8" would then have a post id greater than the 1".

Comment: @JoshLevinson I'm going to have to rewrite the sort method to parse the decimal value based on the text then; give me a bit...

Comment: I appreciate the help. I've updated the question with an each. I didn't realize until Kolink pointed it out that array's can only have integer indeces. I guess it makes sense. I think my original code would work if we could sort the array. Objects can obviously have decimal indeces, but to my knowledge you cannot sort an object.

Comment: @JoshLevinson you can't sort an object because its members are not ordinal.  What you can do is have an array of objects like this `[{'text': optionText, 'elem': optionElement}].sort(function (a, b) { return parseInt(a.text) - parseInt(b.text)); });`  This of course assumes that `text` is the sortable value

Comment: ExplosionPills - the code is now using objects. They aren't sorting quite correctly though. Care to take a stab?

Comment: @JoshLevinson do you have a jsfiddle link for me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24571/discussion-between-josh-levinson-and-explosion-pills)